# Mirroring in SQL Server Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server

I have setup mirroring of a database in SQL Server Standard Edition.

After this I tried to see if the data has been synchronized or not.

I was not able to check data by taking a database snapshot since database snapshots are not available in SQL Server Standard Edition.

Is there any alternative solutions available to verify whether the data is synchronized or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the following system view:

```
SELECT *
FROM master.sys.database_mirroring;
```

There is a wealth of information in there about the status of your mirrored databases.

If the column `mirroring_state_desc` contains 'SYNCHRONIZED' then it is indeed synchronized.

What `SYNCHRONIZED` indicates is that all outstanding transactions from the master have been successfully committed into the mirror database.

If it shows a status of `SYNCHRONIZING` then the mirror is "behind" the principal to some degree.

You can also use the Database Mirroring Monitor app to monitor the status of mirrored databases.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on standard edition there is not much way around and you would have to believe that mirroring is doing its task. Instead of worrying whether data is being sent on mirror or not or whether changes are reflecting you must monitor SEND queue and REDO queue using GUI In this case.

The size of the SEND queue shows how much transaction log has been generated on the principal server, but hasn’t yet been sent to the mirror server. If it’s not zero, it means the mirroring state isn’t synchronized. Furthermore, the size of the SEND queue indicates the amount of data loss that will occur if the principal database suffers a disaster.

If you find the REDO queue size growing, this implies the mirror server can’t keep up with the amount of log being sent from the principal server. It could be there’s additional workload on the mirror server that’s preventing the mirror database log from replaying as fast as possible. It may also be the physical hardware on the mirror server isn’t as capable as that on the principal server.

The REDO queue size shows how much transaction log exists in the mirror database that hasn’t yet been replayed on the mirror database.

These two will help you know how much behind principal is from mirror server. Read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj906367.aspx)

Alternatively you can failover principal to mirror but make sure before failover that mirror is fully synchronized with principal to avoid any data loss.(if possible or when you have maintenance window) to check the status of mirror server. IMO failover is best way here to determine and prove that changes are actually getting reflected if you need to show for some audit purpose with screenshots.